# CSS/JS issue in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, firefox

I am having a weird kind of issue in Firefox. 
I have applied some js to the header of this site http://devignstudios.nl/  so the header is alway sticky when user scroll down the page. 
The sticky header works fine in all browsers except firefox. 
I tried to find the solution but couldn't find a proper answer.

Following is the js

```
var stickyNavTop = $('#header').offset().top;
            var stickyNav = function(){  
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  

            if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {   
                $('#header').addClass('sticky');  
            } else {  
                $('#header').removeClass('sticky');   
            }  
            };  

            stickyNav();  

            $(window).scroll(function() {  
                stickyNav();  
            });
```

Any help here will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: works fine on firefox 33.0.2 on windows 7.

Comment: It's not working flawless on Android Browser either

Comment: well if the browser is under a certain amount of pixels, you remove the sticky header....

Comment: I have 32.0.3 
updating to latest version now

Comment: @epascarello , What do you mean ? I did not understand.

Comment: He is saying that you should remove your sticky header if the client's browser window is smaller than X pixels.

Comment: OH. He is talking about the viewport of site. I do not want to do that right now. My main issue is that sticky header works fine in all browsers but in firefox the header is alwasy sticky.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with the  scrollTop function which doesn't work in all cases on firefox when applied to id and classes. 
Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rHmAA/7/

This is the modified version of your sticky div thing. (for future reference)
The script uses a #stickyheader as a wrapper.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

    var offset;
    if ($('#stickyheader').css('position') == 'relative') {
        offset = $('#stickyheader').outerHeight(true) * 2;
    } else {
        offset = $('#stickyheader').outerHeight(true);
    }
    console.log("offset: " + offset);
    var $parent = $target.offsetParent();
    console.log("$target.offset().top " + $target.offset().top);

    $('#wrapper').animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - offset
    }, 1500, function(){
        window.location.hash = target;
    });

});
```

});